# How to ensure strong password in tank_auth?

Tags: codeigniter-2, tankauth

I Completed registration in Tank_auth for my Project.But I need strong password ensure facility.Will you please help me.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

are you thinking of using some 3rd party lib?? if you are then you might look at [this one](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Random-Password-Generator).